# How to set fixed length to class attributes?

Tags: c#

I am currently doing a project on B+ trees. I want to set my records with fix length attributes such that each record object will be of the same size (bytes) but I am not sure how to go about doing it.

Below is my code for the Record class.

```
 public struct Record
    {
        private string tConst;
        private double averageRating;
        private int numVotes;
        
        public Record(string tConst, double averageRating, int numVotes)
        {
            this.tConst = tConst;
            this.averageRating = averageRating;
            this.numVotes = numVotes;
        }

        public string getTConst()
        {
            return this.tConst;
        }

        public double getAverageRating()
        {
            return this.averageRating;
        }

        public int getNumVotes()
        {
            return this.numVotes;
        }

        public int getBytes()
        {
            return (
                System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(this.tConst) + 
                System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(this.averageRating.ToString()) +
                System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(this.numVotes.ToString())
            );
        }
```

Comment: What if your object needs more bytes than you allow?

Comment: How do you think this could ever work? A `string` can contain an arbitrary number of characters.

Comment: If it is your intention that the strings will all be the same known length: "fixed buffers" - it is, however, an advanced topic that requires `unsafe` code and judicious use of the `fixed` statement. Happy to add more verbose details here, but I want to check if that's what you mean first!